# Change webpage with PHP or Javascript on a listed date or time

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to PHP and I want to know if something like this is possible. Basically on my web server I have multiple index files. Ex. Christmas.html, normal.html, Halloween.html. Is there a way to make an index.php file that will redirect you to a certain page on a certain date? So if it’s about Christmas time, the PHP page will redirect you to the Christmas.html page. Thank you!

I've tried this

```
// For todays date;
Date.prototype.today = function () { 
return ((this.getDate() < 10)?"0":"") + this.getDate() +"/"+    (((this.getMonth()+1) < 10)?"0":"") + (this.getMonth()+1) +"/"+     this.getFullYear();
}

if((new Date().today()) >= "01/08/2014")
{
 location.href ="new location url";
}
else
 {
 location.href="current location url";
}
```

but I don't want to have to change the date every year for it to work again. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: You can do this by compare current date with festival date and redirect your page to particular page

Comment: Please: do _not_ add additional information in comments! Please use the `edit` button below your question. Thanks! It is very hard to read and understand your question otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can use the [header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in PHP to set a new location for example.

```
$month = (int)date('n');
$day = (int)date('j');

if ($month == 12 && $day >= 24 && $day <= 26) {
    header('Location: Christmas.html');
}
```

Comment: I will, definitely give this a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead redirecting, you can use include function.
It will keep your page url same but content will be included within it.

```
include 'Halloween.html';
```